# How I get the Rss XML of google groups I have created?

Tags: google-groups

Hi I have also problem with feed actually the rss I have gotten is of private group when I get logged in it shows me message but it did not show messages when we are not logged in from our email.

This is my public group rss https://groups.google.com/forum/feed/test-shoaib-group/msgs/rss.xml?num=15

And this is my private group rss https://groups.google.com/forum/feed/shoaib-private-group/msgs/rss.xml?num=15 There is Forbidden Error Error 403

Can any body help me that I can get the rss feed messages and show them into my web site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be logged with your google account to see the private rss feed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: First, you must set the Public on the Internet sharing option for the Google Groups for Business service. Learn more about setting sharing options

Next, the owner of the group must make the group's messages accessible to the public, as follows:

- From the Google Groups Home screen, click My groups.
- Click the name of the group you want to make accessible.
- Click Manage then on the left click Permissions > Access permissions.
- In View topics, select Anyone.

[more info here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/181779?hl=en)

**UPDATE**

RSS options for groups not available [more info here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/181779?hl=en).